# netperf socket size vs buffer set for send/recv calls?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, microbenchmark

While I was trying to implement benchmark testware using netperf I happened to read its [manual](https://hewlettpackard.github.io/netperf/doc/netperf.html). Where I got this query

In the TCP_STREAM specific test there are an option to mention `-s` and `-S` to specify local(netperf client), remote(netperf server) socket buffer sizes respectively. Is that a regular BSD socket size? There is also an option to specify the local send message size `-m` and remote receive message size `-M`; Is this the total message size after all TCP/IP encapsulation? Can anybody throw some light on this. It would be great if you can illustrate using a use-case why we need these separate parameters as the BSD socket size appears to be the upper boundary here.

Answer (score 0):

The socket buffer sizes (set via -s and -S) will control how much data may be outstanding on the connection at one time by affecting either the receiver's advertised window (which will be based on the SO_SNDBUF) or how much data the sender can hold waiting for ACKnowledgement (which will be based on SO_SNDBUF).

The send and receive message sizes (-m and -M) control how much data is presented in any one "send" (-m) or requested in any one "recv" (-M) call.

As TCP is a streaming protocol, it is perfectly legal/possible to make a send call with a number of bytes larger than the socket buffer(s).  When the socket is blocking (as netperf uses) it simply means the send call will remain there until the last of its bytes have been put into the send socket buffer.   On the receive side, one can as for more than a socket buffer's worth of data in a single receive, but the semantics are such that the call will return with however many bytes happen to be there at the time if there are any, and will return with however many bytes arrive if the socket buffer was empty at the time of the call (again because netperf uses blocking sockets/calls).